Get Pump.fun bonding curve process and Raydium launch
I am new to Solana and was wondering what would be the simplest way to get the bonding curve progress (the one that is shown on their website) of a token that's trading on Pump.fun. I could compute it locally using the price which I have but I don't know their bonding curve equation. I am currently using Helius for getting transactions on Pump.fun and was wondering if I could use it or if I have to use some sort of ABI and interact with the bonding curve contract. Also another question is how to be notified when the token is launched on Raydium. I guess the solution to that is to listen to the pump.fun contract and filter for a particular interaction with Raydium? But is it the best choice in terms of cost and latency? Would appreciate some guidance! Thanks!

So for getting newly launched pairs on Raydium I just used Helius, monitored the Raydium Liquidity Pool V4 (675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8) use the CREATE_POOL filter. Not sure about calculating the bonding curve progress though

Here there, there a couple of scripts that you can use to check the bonding curve status and to actually constantly monitor when a pump.fun token completes the associated bonding curve and moves to Raydium.
You get both the token address and the new Raydium liquidity pool address for this token printed, which is what most people want.
Fee free to check it out: Listening to pump.fun migrations to Raydium.

"Instead of monitoring every new pool on Raydium, focus only on this address: 39azUYFWPz3VHgKCf3VChUwbpURdCHRxjWVowf5jUJjg. Apply a filter on the 'initialize2' instruction.
This contract manages the migration of tokens from pump.fun to Raydium. The migration completes once the bonding curve is finalized, and the Raydium pool is seeded."
here you can find complete implementation: https://gist.github.com/endrsmar/684c336c3729ec4472b2f337c50c3cdb
